# Uncaught ReferenceError: 'dragLayer' is not defined

Tags: reactjs, plotly.js

I have implemented a scatterplot using react-plotly.js. On the chart, I have a zoomable property which allows user to zoom by dragging on the chart area. Because of this property, the cursor on the chart area is always <-> shape. I would like to change the cursor to 'pointer' when user hovers over the data points. I found this codepen link which provides the solution for my desired behavior.
https://codepen.io/destrada/pen/perVON

But when I try to apply the solution suggested in the link to my code, it throws the following error:
[image]

The way I am implementing the suggested solution is:

```
<Plot
    data={this.prepData(this.state.chartData)}
    onHover={(data) => {
        dragLayer.style.cursor='pointer'}}/>
```

Am I not calling dragLayer function correctly ? Why is dragLayer not being recognized by plotly ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`dragLayer` seems to be an HTML element rather than a function. The issue you're running into is most likely due to where you're defining `dragLayer`. Definition from the codepen sample:

```
dragLayer = document.getElementsByClassName('nsewdrag')[0]
```

It seems the `dragLayer` definition above is out of scope when you're rendering the `Plot` component.

It looks like you're using a React class component so you could do something like:

```
class MyPlot extends Component {
  // ...

  componentDidMount() {
    this.dragLayer = document.getElementsByClassName("nsewdrag")[0];
  }

  // ...

  render() {
    // ...
    return (
      <Plot
        data={this.prepData(this.state.chartData)}
        onHover={data => {
          this.dragLayer.style.cursor = "pointer";
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey great catch! it was due to the scope of this.dragLayer. Though putting it in componentDidMount() didn't work for me. I had to put it under onHover event call. But thanks :)